# Removing unused dependencies form pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am working on a huge spring project and I want to optimize the build time for the project.

So, I ran the `dependency:analyze` to find out there are more than 400 unused dependencies in the project.

Is there any **tool** or **maven command** to update the original pom.xml by removing unused dependencies.

Removing 400+ dependencies manually is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: Plus, other than downloading (you are using caching, right?), more jars don't add measurably to build time in Java; that's one of the platform's major advantages.

Comment: You have more than 400 dependencies in your POM?

Comment: the number 400 can only come from all the transitive dependencies included, if you look inside of your pom file you will only have less than 30 dependencies. Try deleting them one by one and see what happens.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have to run the deploy job like 5-6 times a day. So I cant rely on caching.

Comment: @JAsgarovyes yes, I am including transitive dependencies when I am saying 400. But the thing is I cant totally remove any project from the main pom.xml

I have to edit 17 files to get rid of these dependencies.

Comment: That's called refactoring. The question is why have some many useless dependencies summed up in the pom's...That's the same as continuously refactoring your code.

Answer (score 0):

If dependencies are your bottleneck, then set up an internal Maven repository mirroring the world and tell your build process to use that.